# Getting a css ribbon to appear on selected images only from a django database

Tags: css, django

I am using django framework. I have a css that creates a ribbon on an image. the problem is that I do not want the ribbon on every image in the database. In the HTML file for mt product details I have

```
{% if product.get_image_url %}

<div class="ribbon-wrapper-orange"><div class="ribbon-orange">{{ product.duration }}</div></div>

<a href='{{ product.get_absolute_url }}'><img id='img' src='{{ product.get_image_url }}' class='img-responsive' /></a>

{% endif %}
```

The bove works fine if there is a time duration in the database, but if there is not, then an empty ribbon still comes on the image. Any ideas how I can have the ribbon appear on images with times in the product duration field only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check whether `product.ribbon` is not `None` before rendering the `div`s. Try this:

`{% if product.duration %}<div class="ribbon-wrapper-orange"><div class="ribbon-orange">{{ product.duration }}</div></div>{% endif %}`